# Remove Trailing Parenthetical in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In my attempt to query a table, one of the fields has the occasional observation with a trailing parenthetical. I need to remove the parentheses and the strings they contain.

Example:
**What I Have**
Christopher Columbus (this is what I need to remove)
Mickey Mouse
American Gladiator (parenthetical)

**What I Need**
Christopher Columbus
Mickey Mouse
American Gladiator

Is there some combination of regex/trim() that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) to remove everything from the first `(` (and any preceding whitespace) to the end of the string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(program, '\s*\(.*$', '') AS result
FROM series
```

Output:

```
result
Christopher Columbus
Mickey Mouse
American Gladiator
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=12b6b7836e12f9cc1599aaaba05d518f)

Comment: It looks like this worked! Thank you. I'm trying to understand the regex syntax: it looks for any amount of whitespace, followed by any character match? Why doesn't that remove "Columbus", "Mouse", and "Gladiator"?

Comment: @spencergadd you're right but you missed the `(`. So it looks for whitespace, followed by a `(`, followed by any number of characters up to end of line, and replaces that with nothing (effectively deleting it). I've made a regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/iQ4gMa/1) that shows what is matching and also has an explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no further parenthesis in the names

> ```
> CREATE TABLE series (program varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO series VALUES ('Christopher Columbus (this is what I need to remove)'),
> ('Mickey Mouse'),
> ('American Gladiator (parenthetical)')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT left("program",
> CASE WHEN POSITION('(' IN "program") = 0 tHEN LENGTH("program")
> ELSE POSITION('(' IN "program") -1 END ) FROM series
> ```
>
> ```
> | left                  |
> | :-------------------- |
> | Christopher Columbus  |
> | Mickey Mouse          |
> | American Gladiator    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=28e0b361d937b934a99f14c30f2641ad)*